# why i get multiple and same alerts in manage my alerts in sharepoint when clicking 'alerts me' for a specific item

Tags: sharepoint-online

When i clicked 'alerts me' for a specific item ,then i checked my alerts on 'manage my alerts', it listed 3 same alert messages in 'manage my alerts'.

But for other item, it won't happen like that,just have only  1 alert message in 'manage my alerts'.

What happened to that specific item ? And how to fix?

Comment: May be you have subscribed for the alert multiple time for the first item.

Comment: @ Jefin Mathew ,so do you know how to  unsubscribe and make the alert normal .I deleted that alert and subscribe again , it still gives me the 3 same alert in 'manage my alerts'.